# How to define type lambda properly?

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicits

I used `=:=` as example type lambda for purpose of making simple minimal example.

`=:=` type take two arguments, I'd like to curry one at type level.

I take naive implementation `type Curry[G] = {type l[L] = L =:= G}` but in practical uses it causes errors:

```
type X = Int
type Y = Int

type CurryInt[T] = T =:= Int
type Curry[G] = {type l[L] = L =:= G}
type CurrStatic = {type l[L] = L =:= Int}
object CurryObj {type l[L] = L =:= Int}

trait Apply[P[_], T]
implicit def liftApply[P[_], T](implicit ev : P[T]) = new Apply[P,T] {}

implicitly[Apply[CurryInt, Y]] // ok
implicitly[Apply[Curry[X]#l, Y]] // fails
implicitly[Apply[Curry[X]#l, Y]](liftApply) // fails
implicitly[Apply[Curry[X]#l, Y]](liftApply[Curry[X]#l, Y]) // ok
implicitly[Apply[CurrStatic#l, Y]] // fails
implicitly[Apply[CurryObj.l, Y]] // ok
```

Type inference breaks here. How should I define type lambdas to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Consider this simplified version of your example:

```scala
trait Secret
type Curry = { type l[L] = Secret }

def foo[P[_], T](ev : P[T]) = ???
val bar: Curry#l[Int] = ???

foo(bar)
```

When calling `foo` the value `bar` is simply of type `Secret`, the compiler doesn't know from where your particular `Secret` comes from.

Your `bar` value is just a `Secret`, and it doesn't maintain information pointing back to `Curry#l[Int]`.

The compiler cannot infer that `P => Curry#l` and `T => Int`.

The compiler only sees the `Secret` and loses the `Curry#l` context despite annotating the type with `Curry#l[Int]` instead of `Secret`.

Another example (coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721127/how-to-infer-the-right-type-parameter-from-a-projection-type) question), exposing a similar behaviour:

```scala
trait Curry { type l }
trait CurryB extends Curry { type l = String }

def foo[P <: Curry](x: P#l) = ???
val bar: CurryB#l = ???

foo(bar)
```

---

`CurryObj` situation is different, consider that `CurryInt#l`, `Curry#l`, and `CurrStatic#l` are just type aliases. `CurryObj.l`, instead, is an actual type, part of the concrete object `CurryObj`.

Let's have a look to this (REPL):

```
scala> trait Secret
defined trait Secret

scala> type Curry = { type l[L] = Secret }
defined type alias Curry

scala> object CurryObj { type l[L] = Secret }
defined object CurryObj

scala> object S extends Secret
defined object S

scala> val foo0: Curry#l[Int] = S
foo0: Secret = S$@2c010477

scala> val foo1: CurryObj.l[Int] = S
foo1: CurryObj.l[Int] = S$@2c010477
```

Note that the type alias `Curry#l[Int]` -> `Secret` is resolved immediately, instead the actual type `CurryObj.l[Int]` is kept.

Comment: type `Curry` is like `CurrStatic` from my example. It looks very alike to `CurryObj`. Why the type information is saved in one case and losed in another?

Comment: It has meaning. But in my case `Curry#l` is used without applying `Int` to it. And `Secret` has type parameter too, so it could not be eliminated. As I had seen in `-Yinfer-debug`, type parameter is preserved but in a unusual form

Comment: Using your `Curry[G] = {type l[L] = =:=[L,G]}` the type `Curry[Int]#l` is "resolved" (it can be "eliminated") to `=:=[L, Int]` that is again incompatible with type `P[T]` of your `liftApply`.

Comment: `L` is exactly what is needed - single unfilled "hole" in the type

Answer (score 2):

slightly more verbose, but compiles :) (scala 2.12.3)

```
  type X = Int
  type Y = Int

  type CurryInt[T] = T =:= Int
  type Curry[G] = {type l[L] = =:=[L, G]}
  type CurrStatic = {type l[L] = L =:= Int}
  object CurryObj {type l[L] = L =:= Int}

  trait Apply[P[_], T]
  implicit def liftApply[P[_], T](implicit ev : P[T]) = new Apply[P,T] {}


  type L1[R] = =:=[R, X]
  type L2[R] = =:=[R, Int]
  implicitly[Apply[CurryInt, Y]] // ok
  implicitly[Apply[L1, Y]] // ok
  implicitly[Apply[L1, Y]](liftApply[L1, Y]) // ok
  implicitly[Apply[Curry[X]#l, Y]](liftApply[Curry[X]#l, Y]) // ok
  implicitly[Apply[L2, Y]] // ok
  implicitly[Apply[CurryObj.l, Y]] // ok
```

Comment: shortly: does not use type projection. Type declaration are allowed to have unbound variables

Comment: You weren't specific as to your requirements, however this solution compiles why are you trying to go with the 'type projection'? Is it just an exercicse?

Comment: I was oblivious that unbound types are allowed in type expression. So I tried to encode something like `λx.λy.x==y` in type level. I could not imagine that simple `λx.x==y` would be correct scala expression.

Comment: Your answer solves my specific use case replacing type lambdas with named expressions. But generally type lambdas still causes type inference errors and I could not grasp why.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that scala compiler could not handle naked types from type projections. I traced `-Ytyper-debug` output and found that all needed type information is carried away but is rejected for no apparent reason. But it still possible to get type lambdas wrapping expressions inside a trait. [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006565/how-to-abstract-over-type-kind/46015194#46015194) gave me an insight towards solution.

```
type X = Int
type Y = Int

trait Wrap {
  type l[T]
}
trait GenWrap[W[_]] extends Wrap {
  final type l[T] = W[T]
}

type CInt[T] = T =:= Int
class CurryInt extends Wrap {type l[T] = T =:= Int}
class Curry[U] extends Wrap {type l[T] = T =:= U}
type TCurry[U] = Wrap {type l[T] = T =:= U}

trait Apply[W <: Wrap, T]
implicit def lift[W <: Wrap, T](implicit ev : W#l[T]) = new Apply[W,T] {}

implicitly[Apply[CurryInt, Y]]
implicitly[Apply[Curry[X], Y]]
implicitly[Apply[TCurry[X], Y]]
implicitly[Apply[GenWrap[CInt], Y]]
```